# Windows doesn't recognize HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, diskpart

I bought a computer and I installed Windows 10. I bought it with 256 GB of SSD and 1000 GB of HDD. I installed the OS on the SSD. When I installed it, the operation system can't find my hard disk. I tried to run diskpart and got the following result:

```
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          238 GB      0 B        *


DISKPART> select disk 0
Disk 0 is now the selected disk.


DISKPART> list partition
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System              62 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Unknown           1024 KB    63 MB
  Partition 3    Unknown            927 GB    64 MB
  Partition 4    Unknown           4095 MB   927 GB
```

This is the result for the SSD (which is working):

```
DISKPART> select disk 1
Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Reserved            16 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            238 GB    17 MB
```

Disk management:

[disk managment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esmvf.png)

When I tried to assign a disk letter to the first disk I saw disk with 60MB (the size of the first partition) and not 1000 GB (the real size of the disk). How can I assign a disk letter to specific partition (the third partition)?

```
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------  
  Volume 0                      FAT    Partition     62 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    238 GB  Healthy    Boot

DISKPART>
```

I'd be happy to get help!

**Edit:**
In Disk Managment I can't choose the "Format" option.

[Can't choose options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFC7p.png)

Comment: The installation is atypical. Typically the EFI partition would be in the SSD leaving the HDD for data only. But it works like it is, the only problem being you can't remove the HDD or Windows will not boot. You can use the remaining space with one or more partitions formatted with a file system Windows understands so, you can just format the partition 3 as NTFS and it will automatically have a drive letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation is atypical*. Typically the EFI partition would be in the SSD leaving the HDD for data only.

It works like it is now but you can't remove or replace the HDD or Windows will not boot.

You can use the remaining space with one or more partitions formatted with a file system Windows understands so, you can just **format the Disk 0 - Partition 3 as NTFS and it will automatically have a drive letter** or **delete and create a new partition or more than one if you like**. The reason why you can't just assign a drive letter is because of "Partition type: Unknown". It has a file system not recognized by Windows therefore it can't be mounted.

- This happened due to "incorrect" manual partitioning. With blank drives, unless there's a compelling reason for a different schema, users should let the OS installer create its own partitions. This would have resulted, in this case, in two partitions - ESP (FAT32) and Windows system partition (NTFS), the "drive C:".

Comment: How can I format specific partition as NTFS? diskpart allowing to format a volume (and the volume is the first partition and not the third). Can you explain how to solve my problem?

Comment: You can use Disk Management for that if you like. And you CAN delete that partition (and everything else **except EFI**) and create a new one or more than one. I really don't understand why you're complicating things so much.

Comment: I opened the Disk Managment. The only option that I have is: "Delete Volume". I can't choose the Format option. I will add an image to my post

Comment: So do it. Then create a new partition.

Comment: it worked! Microsoft support told me it was a hardware problem :P

Comment: They're not seeing what you showed us, probably. Also you forgot to mention to them and here that the unknown type partitions were from a Linux installation attempt. I haven't mentioned it before because not really relevant for the solution to achieve your goal. And that's why Windows Disk Management was having an hard time dealing with it. Next question, please, remember to provide all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

From disk part you have to select partition then assign the letter:

```
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          238 GB      0 B        *


DISKPART> select disk 0
Disk 0 is now the selected disk.


DISKPART> list partition
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System              62 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Unknown           1024 KB    63 MB
  Partition 3    Unknown            927 GB    64 MB
  Partition 4    Unknown           4095 MB   927 GB
```

After you select the disk 0 do a

```
select partition 3
assign
```

If you prefer to do it via disk management right click on the disk partition you interested with:
[image]

Choose one letter and you are done!

Comment: Partition 3 is type "unknown". It needs to be formatted first and once done it will have a drive letter.

Comment: You should post that as an answer @gabrielagarcia